# I am using command npm install in react but I am getting the errors

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You'll probably running a outdated npm, lockfileVersion@2 is for npm v7 and above

Comment: You can't install `fsevents` on Windows. It's not clear what you're installing that's trying to do that anyway.